# React Native Google SignIn Dependency Crashing the app

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I am building an app in react native that requires Google sign-in. I have built my app using expo. I am using the `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` library and it requires to run native iOS code. So when I install the cocoapod dependencies and try to run it using the command
`npx expo run:ios`

I get the following errors in the console.

```
The following build commands failed:         PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/salmanmajid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoogleSignin-abtmegusgbluxfatgbyobrwohomi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E00019B70.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods') (1 failure) Build logs written to /Users/salmanmajid/Documents/Nahom Projects/React native/Reusable Components/GoogleSignin/.expo/xcodebuild.log
```

Here is the log file [attached](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1poc3qzy-4Q0ZUG3kSNO1bt37Z4GzdWZbi-VQ4vSFuaQ/edit?usp=sharing).

I am using

`expo: 50.0.7`

`react-native: 0.73.4`

The project built successfully once and I was able to start the login flow but after that not sure what happened, it stopped working all of a sudden. I didn't make any updates to any dependencies or anything. Help me figure out the issue please.

Comment: Suggesting Solutions along with edits would be more helpful and much strong gesture of keeping this community up and running.

Comment: Go to your Xcode Project Folder, run 'pod install', and see what will happen.

Comment: already tried that. Doesn't work